# Remove items from a colletion with the Rally REST for .NET API

Tags: c#, .net, rally

I'm using the REST toolkit, and there's lots of cool stuff, but I don't see a way in it to remove an item from a collection as is mentioned in the API documentation:

Items can be removed from Modifiable collections by sending a POST request to a collection reference url with a body containing an array of items to remove. Example payload to remove a tag from a collection by a POST request to https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/defect/49103/tags/remove:

Anybody done this?  Got code?

Answer (score 1):

v3.1.1 of the toolkit added support for adding to and removing from collections.
Check it out!

http://rallytools.github.io/RallyRestToolkitFor.NET/html/efed9f73-559a-3ef8-5cd7-e3039040c87d.htm

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no convenience method in the toolkit yet to remove a collection element form the collection, in order to remove a tag from a collection of tags you have to replace an existing collection with a copy of that collection minus the change you intended to make to the original collection, and then update the story with that new tag collection.

This code removes a tag from a story. In this example I strip the last tag of the collection. For example, if I have a collection of 2 tags, the code leaves one tag, and when this code is run again, the last tag is removed and the story is no longer tagged.
As an alternative, a commented out condition skips an unwanted tag based on tag name.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Rally.RestApi;
using Rally.RestApi.Response;

namespace aRESTremoveTagFromStory
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Initialize the REST API
            RallyRestApi restApi;
            restApi = new RallyRestApi("user@co.com", "secret", "https://rally1.rallydev.com", "v2.0");

            //Set our Workspace and Project scopings
            String workspaceRef = "/workspace/1111"; //replace this OID with an OID of your workspace
            String projectRef = "/project/2222";     //replace this OID with an OID of your project
            bool projectScopingUp = false;
            bool projectScopingDown = true;

            Request storyRequest = new Request("HierarchicalRequirement");

            storyRequest.Workspace = workspaceRef;
            storyRequest.Project = projectRef;
            storyRequest.ProjectScopeUp = projectScopingUp;
            storyRequest.ProjectScopeDown = projectScopingDown;

            storyRequest.Fetch = new List<string>()
                {
                    "Name",
             "FormattedID",
                     "Tags"
                };

            storyRequest.Query = new Query("FormattedID", Query.Operator.Equals, "US123"); //replace this FormattedID with FormattedID valid in your workspace
            QueryResult queryStoryResults = restApi.Query(storyRequest);

           //create an array to contain modified list of tags for this story. 
            ArrayList tagList = new ArrayList();

            foreach (var s in queryStoryResults.Results)
            {

                Console.WriteLine("FormattedID: " + s["FormattedID"] + " Name: " + s["Name"]);
                Console.WriteLine("----------");
        ///query for Tags collection on this story    
                Request tagRequest = new Request(s["Tags"]);
                QueryResult queryTagResult = restApi.Query(tagRequest);
                int count = 0;
                if (queryTagResult.TotalResultCount > 0)
                {
                    foreach (var t in queryTagResult.Results)
                    {
                        var tagName = t["Name"];
                        var tagRef = t["_ref"];
                        Console.WriteLine(tagName + "  " + tagRef + " " + tagOID);

                        if (count < queryTagResult.TotalResultCount - 1) //skips the last tag
                        //if (tagName != "tag2") //skips the tag with name "tag2"
                        {
                            DynamicJsonObject newTag = new DynamicJsonObject();
                            newTag["_ref"] = tagRef;
                            tagList.Add(newTag);
                        }
                        count++;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("no tags found");
                }

                DynamicJsonObject newTagCollection = new DynamicJsonObject();
                newTagCollection["Tags"] = tagList;

                OperationResult updateResult = restApi.Update(s["_ref"], newTagCollection);
            }
        }
    }
}
```